# Android webview not showing offline page saved by service worker

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, service-worker, offline

I have a webpage with service worker, that in offline mode, mobile Chrome can still show my offline.html.

Now I have an Android APP with a webview to show the page, but when there is no internet, there is a Android error page saying `"Webpage not available` `The webpage at xxxxxx could not be loaded because: net:ERR_FAILED"`

How can I solve it? Can I prevent checking of internet connection in the Andoird APP? Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using any external resources in your webpage like external JS, CSS, any other script? maybe the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override your own `WebViewClient` and check the Internet connection in in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
public boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {   

    ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
      context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
        && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
        && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
}

class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (!checkInternetConnection(this)) {
      view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
    } else {
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }     
    return true;
  }
}
```

And ofcourse, set your custom `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient())
```

Also, put `filename.html` in your Android project assets folder